# Fatal error with template type-alias

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, thrust

Note: scroll to bottom of question for update.

When compiling my C++ program with Visual Studio 2017 (using `/std:c++latest`), I get an error that reads:

> 'thrust::tuple_element': template parameter 'N': 'i': a variable with non-static storage duration cannot be used as a non-type  argument

The portion of code that produces the error is the following:

```
namespace thrust
{
template<size_t i, class... Types>
using tuple_element_t = typename tuple_element<i,Types...>::type;
```

The error is produced specifically by the line that begins with `using`. The link that Visual Studio provides to explain the error (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2971) is rather straightforward, explaining that a local variable cannot be used as a template argument. However, I do not understand how that error applies in this case - the parameter `i` was declared as shown in the code above as `size_t i` in what I understand to be the normal way to define templates.

Furthermore, after this error is produced, Visual Studio creates a brief pop-up that reads

> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler has stopped working
>
> Windows is checking for a solution to the problem...

and afterwards in the error list a second error reads "unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation". This fatal error and the above described error are the only two errors.

Why is the compiler producing the first error and how can I fix it? And why might this error cause the compiler to crash like this?

By the way, the `tuple_element` that appears in the error-producing code is from the Thrust parallel algorithms library (see https://thrust.github.io/doc/structthrust_1_1tuple__element.html).

Additional note: the usage of `tuple_element_t` occurs as shown below.

```
namespace tuple_repeat_ns
{
template<typename T, typename IndexSequence>
struct tuple_repeat_helper;

template<typename T, size_t... I>
struct tuple_repeat_helper<T, std::index_sequence<I...>>
{
    using type = tuple<tuple_element_t<I-I,tuple<T>>...>;
};

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct tuple_repeat_traits : tuple_repeat_helper<T,std::make_index_sequence<N>>
{
    using typename tuple_repeat_helper<T,std::make_index_sequence<N>>::type;
};

template<size_t I, typename T>
auto tuple_repeat_identity(const T& t)
{
    return t;
}

template<typename T, size_t... I>
auto tuple_repeat(const T& t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return make_tuple(tuple_repeat_identity<I>(t)...);
}
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
using tuple_repeat_t = typename tuple_repeat_ns::tuple_repeat_traits<T, N>::type;

template<size_t N, typename T>
auto tuple_repeat(const T& t)
{
    return tuple_repeat_ns::tuple_repeat(t, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

template<size_t N, typename T>
struct computes_tuple_repeat
{
    auto operator()(const T& t) const
    {
        return tuple_repeat<N,T>(t);
    }
};
```

Also, here is some of the actual compiler error output:

> 1>[my_project]\core\thrust_wrapper.h(71): error C2971: 'thrust::tuple_element': template parameter 'N': 'i': a variable with non-static storage duration cannot be used as a non-type argument
>   1>c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v8.0\include\thrust\tuple.h(67): note: see declaration of 'thrust::tuple_element'
>   1>[my_project]\core\tuple_repeat.h(9): note: see declaration of 'i'
>   1>[my_project]\core\tuple_repeat.h(9): note: see reference to alias template instantiation 'tuple_element_t>' being compiled
>       with
>       [
>           T=unsigned char
>       ]
>   1>[my_project]\core\tuple_repeat.h(14): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'tuple_repeat_ns::tuple_repeat_helper>' being compiled
>       with
>       [
>           T=unsigned char,
>           _Ty=::size_t
>       ]
>   1>[my_project]\core\tuple_repeat.h(32): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'tuple_repeat_ns::tuple_repeat_traits' being compiled
>       with
>       [
>           T=unsigned char
>       ]
>   1>[my_project]\core\types.h(39): note: see reference to alias template instantiation 'tuple_repeat_t' being compiled
>   1>[my_project]\core\thrust_wrapper.h(71): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation

Thank you for the help!

Update: it appears that replacing the line in `tuple_repeat_helper` that reads

```
using type = tuple<tuple_element_t<I-I, tuple<T>>...>;
```

with the line

```
using type = tuple<typename thrust::tuple_element<I-I,tuple<T>>::type...>;
```

averts the compiler error. This seems to solve the question of how to fix the problem, but why the error occurred to begin with is still a mystery to me. I essentially just substituted the definition of the alias instead of just using the alias... and that fixed it?

I will probably try to put together a more proper verifiable example later and possibly submit a bug report.

Comment: Please show us how you *use* the type-alias. Preferably as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where are you using `tuple_element_t` and how do you instantiate it?

Comment: this looks like internal compiler error. Please provide full output that compiler gives you about this error

Comment: You can fix this compiler bug by accepting a job at Microsoft and presumably working in the VC++ team. Otherwise you will have to wait until Microsoft fix it. What are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: Please don't assume compiler makers are tracking SO, *[report](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/05/05/the-easiest-way-to-file-bugs-and-send-error-logs-for-visual-studio-2015/)* the bug to them, so that there is a *chance* of it ever being solved.

Comment: I'm not sure that is a compiler error, I think Visual Studio used to let you omit the `typename` part, but doesn't anymore because letting you omit it is non-standard behaviour. I could be wrong, but that seems to be the case. Either way you should submit the resolution as an actual answer to the question and accept it (the marking the question as answered) since this has technically been resolved